# Mouse pointer freezing up

Tags: 11.10, mouse, freeze

I'm not sure if it should be asked here or on forums but I'll still put it up here to get discussion started,

So 2 days back I upgraded to 11.10 64bit beta.
There are few crashes which I already reported through bug reporting.

But my mouse pointer (laptop touchpad) for some reason seems to be freezing up.
I'm trying to decide the reason/moment for a freeze but can't seem to come to conclusion.

1. Mostly when I press enter for first time? or ctrl+Enter? <-- these are stones thrown in dark, as those are the things I mostly do after starting up.

But yea, has anyone else seen/read/experienced something similar?

Ohh btw my USB mouse work completely fine so I think only touchpad issue,
I would appreciate if anyone know how to remove and install touchpad kernel drivers (hopefully rmmod and modprobe) I'll see if that helps.

My lsusb looks something like this:

```
Bus 007 Device 004: ID 0a5c:4502 Broadcom Corp. Keyboard (Boot Interface Subclass)
Bus 007 Device 005: ID 0a5c:4503 Broadcom Corp. Mouse (Boot Interface Subclass)
```

Thanks

[edit]: Other things that I noticed, power button (on laptop) doesn't work, and shortcuts such as ctrl+alt+L doesn't work

Comment: Ohh btw sorry can't create tags Ubuntu11.10 and 64bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if anyone still following this question 11.10 by default disable mouse while typing.
So I unchecked an option to disable mouse.

```
System Settings -> Mouse and Touchpads -> Touchpads --> UNTICK disable while typing
```